# After Logout, login with the same user credentials is not working with Mongo Realm

Tags: xamarin.ios, realm

I am using below code to log out the the current logged in user

```
 public async Task Logout()
     {
        SecureStorage.RemoveAll();
        await RealmMain.realmApp.CurrentUser.LogOutAsync();
     }
```

Then, I use below code to sign in back again.

```
public async Task<bool> LoginWithCredential(Action<string> error)
    {
        try {
            var credentials = Credentials.EmailPassword(userId, pass);

            var user = await RealmMain.realmApp.LogInAsync(credentials);


            return user != null;               
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            SecureStorage.RemoveAll();
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            error(exceptionText);
            return false;

        }

    }
```

RealmMain Class is like this below.

```
    public sealed class RealmMain
    {
        private const string AppId = "*************";
        public static App realmApp = App.Create(AppId);

public SyncConfiguration ConfigForSync
        {
            get
            {
                var temp = new SyncConfiguration(realmApp.CurrentUser.Id, realmApp.CurrentUser)
                {
                   //  EncryptionKey = AppContext.GetBytes(AppContext.DbKey)
                };
                Console.WriteLine(temp.EncryptionKey);
                return temp;
            }
        }
 public static RealmMain Instance { get; } = new RealmMain();

        private RealmMain()
        {

        }
}
```

Problem here is - When is log out and then try to sign in with the same user credential.

I get below error.

"Realms.Sync.Exceptions.AppException: Unknown: must authenticate first
at Realms.Sync.App.LogInAsync (Realms.Sync.Credentials credentials)"

If I use some different user to sign in after logging out.

I get this.

[image]

In nutshell Logout and then login is not working for me, I have to quit the app to make it work every time.

Any suggestion to solve this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Is something missing from your Logout code? You don't seem to be calling `user.LogOutAsync` but rather you're reopening the Realm instance after wiping SecureStorage.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, It was trying something out that partially edited code I pasted. I have now corrected it.  Problem is still the same.  I logout but can't login back in(after killing and launching again everything works) without "must authenticate" thing

Comment: Hm, this sounds like a bug then. If you can extract a simple repro for this, please open an issue in the [Realm .NET repo](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/new/choose).

Comment: Will create a repo and give link here